# How can I change the default Cordova Splashscreen in PhoneGap?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have no idea where/how to change the Default Cordova splashscreen in PhoneGap. I've tried adding my own splashscreen but it somehow still brings up the Cordova Splashscreen as you open the app. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Go to your_poroject_name_dir/Resources/splash,  there are splash images . You can replace your images with same naming conventions and size

Comment: i tried this and it still does not seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: your cordova version..?